# captured self gets released inside a dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I am experiencing an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error inside my app within a block that, as of my understanding, should actually capture everything involved in this, making it impossible that it is released inside the block. (ARC is enabled)

Here is my code:

```
- (void)_perform_async_onqueue:(void (^)(void))task {
    dispatch_async(self.workerQueue, task);
}

- (void)cancel {
    [self _perform_async_onqueue:^{
        // operation is strongly retained by self.
        // operation is also retained by an operation queue.
        // within `cancel` the operation is released from the operation queue
        [self.operation cancel];
    }
}];
```

This crashes inside `[self.operation cancel]`. `self.operation` is a subclass of `NSOperation`. The operation's `cancel` method in detail:

```
- (void)cancel {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];
    _cancelled = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _finished = YES;
    _executing = NO;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"]; // CRASH (debugger lists `self` [= the operation] as `nil` in this line
}
```

As of my understanding, the first `self` should be retained inside the dispatched block. As `self` has a `strong` reference to `operation`, this should also be in memory until the end of the block execution. How can this lead to a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT :

Don't implement cancel method in your NSOperation subclass. Just call :

```
[self.operation cancel];
```

A good tuto [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

Comment: Sadly that doesn't solve the issue. I was almost certain that it would be some kind of race condition but wanted to understand why... it seems like it isn't any... that is even more confusing to me now. :/

Comment: mmh...what happens with NSLock ? NSLock *myLock; [myLock lock]; [self willChangeValueForKey:@”someKey”]; someKey = somethingElse; [self didChangeValueForKey:@”someKey”]; [myLock unlock];

Comment: that results in the same issue :(

Comment: Is 'self' is becoming 'nil' just after [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"]; ? Not before ?

Comment: As of my understanding it will get `nil` while executing this line. I can't break there as this only happens from time to time. If it would become `nil` before the line, this line should not do anything as a message would be send to `nil`, right?

Comment: Wait. I read that specs about NSOperation, it is KVO compliant and you don't need to update flags : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW18. Look at the cancel command. Don't implement it. Just subclass NSOperation and call cancel method.

Comment: This is an asynchronous operation so I think I have to trigger KVO notifications myself, otherwise the operation queue does not remove the operation from the queue. I used `AFNetworking` as an example while implementing the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Methods don't have strong references to self. If self is deallocated while a method is being called, you are on your own. (That's why you get a warning if you call a method on a weak object, because the object might go away while the method is running).

You can assign SomeClass* myself = self; and that will keep self alive until the end of the method.

You can also implement your own dealloc (which just calls [super dealloc] automatically) and set a breakpoint to find out *when exactly* self is deallocated, to understand things better.

Comment: That doesn't do the trick either. Also, in my understanding it shouldn't make any difference if I keep a strong `self` or a strong `myself` in my block.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue:

It turns out that the described behaviour is working totally fine. The issue is that the `NSOperation` that is used here is a custom, asynchronous operation that has implemented cancel in the wrong way: If you cancel an operation **before** it has been started by the `NSOperationQueue` the operation queue then overreleases the operation. This is the reason for the operation being deallocated even if there is still a strong reference that should hold it.

I'll go file a rdar for that.